# How can I convert a PDB file to a data frame in the R language?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I tried this:

```
proteins <- read.pdb("exampleFile.pdb")
```

And then I tried to convert proteins to a data frame:

```
as.data.frame(proteins)
```

But R is saying it can not coerce class "c("pdb", "sse")" to a data frame. I'm using the bio3d package.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the atoms of the PDB file you can access them via [`atom`](http://thegrantlab.org/bio3d/html/read.pdb.html).

> **atom**
>
> a data.frame containing all atomic coordinate ATOM and HETATM data, with a row per ATOM/HETATM and a column per record type.

---

```
library('bio3d')
protein <- read.pdb('~/Downloads/1ubq.pdb')
df <- as.data.frame(protein$atom)
print(df)
```

> ```
>      type eleno elety  alt resid chain resno insert      x      y      z    o     b segid elesy charge
> 1     ATOM     1     N <NA>   MET     A     1   <NA> 27.340 24.430  2.614 1.00  9.67  <NA>     N   <NA>
> 2     ATOM     2    CA <NA>   MET     A     1   <NA> 26.266 25.413  2.842 1.00 10.38  <NA>     C   <NA>
> 3     ATOM     3     C <NA>   MET     A     1   <NA> 26.913 26.639  3.531 1.00  9.62  <NA>     C   <NA>
> ```
>
> [...]

Comment: What if, after imported and manipulated the protein$atom, I would like to save the data as a .pdb file?

Comment: @PersianK can you open a new question?